# Count many weeks between current date and the date on sqlite database Android

Tags: android, date, datediff, week-number

I've got a question about counting the weeks between the current date and the date on SQLite.

I am trying to put date data on DBAdapter Class to SharedMemory :

```
SharedPreferences user = getSharedPreferences(USER, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = user.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.putString("full_date", fullDate);
```

Now, on my Activity :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(USER, 0);
fullDateM = sharedPreferences.getString("full_date","");

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date today = null;
try {
    today = df.parse(fullDateM);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar now2 = Calendar.getInstance();
now.getTime();
now2.setTime(today);

long milis1 = now2.getTimeInMillis();
long milis2 = now.getTimeInMillis();

long diff = milis2 - milis1;

long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

But, I got an error to get a value of `diffDays`. And I've checked that `fullDateM` is not null, there's value = "2012-04-27".
And another question : how to set `diffDays` to difference of weeks in that code?

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: i got an error : E/AndroidRuntime(29737): on line => now2.setTime(today);

Comment: I'm not really sure how your code compiles. now2.setTime() takes a long as a parameter and you are passing it a Dat object. Can you post the entire stack trace please?